# css way to make appear list elements <li/> with certain class on top of list

Tags: css

Is there any css way to bubble up `<li>` elements with some class on top of list. I guess I have come across some way to do this in the past but cant remember how to do this exactly.

Please note I dont need to rearrange in markup. Just make the elements with certain class *appear* as if  on top of other elements without that class.

Can anyone tell if there is some way to do this?

Comment: User with 5 gold, 42 silver, 97 bronze, and question like this

Comment: what do you mean when you say bubble up?

Comment: @NathanLee: appear on top of list(ofcourse, i dont expect they move/rearrange in DOM!)

Answer (score 2):

With pure CSS, you can move an element to the top of the list using absolute positioning, though it would not actually be at the top of the list as far as the markup is concerned.  What you want to do can be achieved with javascript however.  Using jQuery, you would want to do something along these lines:

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="myList">
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
    <li>Fourth</li>
    <li class="top">First</li>
    <li>Fifth</li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var list = $('#myList');
    list.children('li.top').remove().prependTo(list);
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/tMWJs/

**Edit:**

To do this with pure CSS, use absolute positioning.  Here is an example of the css you would need:

```
ul#myList {position:relative; margin-top:40px;}
ul#myList li {line-height:20px;}
li.top {position:absolute; top:-20px;}
```

If you have multiple elements to move, this approach would need tinkering to position each element seperately, and is probably not suitable.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/sp73f/

Comment: i dont want it to be rearranged in markup or DOM just make appear as it they are on top

Comment: Answer updated with an example of the absolute positioning method I mentioned.

Comment: & what if when there are multiple elements with class `top` in the list, they all collapse in 1

Comment: Precisely, there isn't a clean way to do this with css.  You would have to assign each element a different class / id in order to style them separately and then adjust the margin at the top of the list to accommodate the list items.  Javascript is a more appropriate solution as it also caters for those who are not looking at your site but interpreting it via screen reading software (the visually impaired and of course, Google).